# Run "rails s" on another directory in a single line

Tags: command-line, cron

I wanted to make a crontab expression at boot, running `rails s` in another directory. I can't find how to change directory in the same expression.

I've tried `rails s /directory` but it doesn't work

Could you guide me?

Thank you

Comment: `cd /directory && rails s`?

Comment: It doesn't work inside crontab. I use sudo crontab but even after doing a .sh with that in it, it doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work? Does `ruby` not run at all, or does it run in some other directory?

Comment: The problem is in crontab. I've found some ways to do it in the terminal, but it just doesn't work in crontab. I have other crontab's processes that work but this doesn't work...

Comment: Yes, but does `ruby` run in a crontab at all? It is likely not in cron's `$PATH`. Does `/path/to/rails s /directory` work?

Comment: This solved the problem. In the `.sh` file I specified the rails' path and it worked OK. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in crontab. I solved it with this line:

```
@reboot sh /path/to/sh-script
```

and in the script I put

```
cd /path/to/rails-app && /usr/local/bin/rails s
```

Thank you